# JNI: Unsatisfied Link Error when passing parameters

Tags: java-native-interface

I'm kinda' new to `JNI`, but been reading alot about `JNI` when I wanted to use a legacy dll in my project.
Quick enough, I found out that I can't parameters to native methods. Here's an example that I tried to code with no success:

```
Hello.java:
package HelloWorld;

    Public class Hello {
    Private static native int HelloWorld();
    Private static native int Mirror(int a);
    Static {
      System.loadLibrary("Example"); //got path in            
                    vm arguments - works.
    }
    Public static void main(String[] args) {
    Int a = 8;
    System.out.println(Mirror(a));
    }
```

Used javah to create header which got me this signature: 
    `JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_HelloWorld_Hello_Mirror (JNIEnv *, jclass, jint);`

Wrote a cpp:
Same signature as the h with impl of: `"return 1";`

That's it and... This is the error I get from eclipse:
`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: HelloWorld/Hello.Mirror(I)I
at HelloWorld.Hello.main (Hello.java:14)`

---

These are my ideas:
A. Saw something about c and cpp, am I mixing things.
B. jdk or stuff?
C. The library loads perfectly (checked the other function that does not get parameters), maybe the types are incompatible?

Stuck on this for a while, Hope you guys can help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!
Just needed to add '{' around both functions in the cpp file, after the "extern c" command...